# Zip file creating in reactjs with .net api force window to reload by showing content changed in debugger mode

Tags: javascript, .net, reactjs, webapi

I am currently doing react js project with .net api.
I am trying to create zip file on dropdown value changes.

zip created successfully but urge window to load forecefully. In debugger mode It shows content from base changed or content-changed.

Please help me out.

Comment: Please consider adding your current source code to the question, so we can better understand what is wrong.

Comment: ok I will provide you please leave your email sir so that I contact you